# Installing Parse Server Generic Email Adapter

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, parse-server

I use parse-server with AWS elastic beanstalk.

There was the mailgun email adapter installed as default, but I want to install the generic email adapter so I can send e-mails with a gmail account. I want to install the plugin below but I do not now how to.

[The Parse Server Generic Email Adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-server-generic-email-adapter)

The command to install is as below:

```
$ npm install --save parse-server-generic-email-adapter
```

But I am not very professional in server side. Generally what I do is open terminal from my mac computer and write `eb init` then make changes in the index and cloud code file and write `eb deploy`.

I don't know where and how to run the command above to install the email adapter. First I run `eb init`, then `eb labs download` and in the location where the sever files are downloaded; I try to run the command above from terminal and I get the messages as below:

```
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 file2
       install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
       install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

I found how to do it, if you use elastic beanstalk with parse-server, and want to use generic mail adapter;

1) in your package.json file dependencies add:

```
"parse-server-generic-email-adapter": "0.0.4"
```

2) in your index.js file - email adapter part, add:

```
module: 'parse-server-generic-email-adapter',
 options: {
  service: 'Gmail',
  email: 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com',
  password: 'xxxxxxx',
}
```

And deploy your files to your elastic beanstalk server with `eb deploy`.